# Elasticsearch 7.7.1 shards getting unassigned

Tags: elasticsearch

We recently upgraded our elasticsearch cluster from 5.6.16 to 7.7.1.

After that sometimes I am observing that few of the shards not getting assigned.

My node stats is placed [here](https://jsonblob.com/b99c4071-2a74-11eb-ae20-7b4f84b0b1cb).

The allocation explanation for an `unassigned` shard is like below

```
ubuntu@platform2:~$      curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
>   "index": "denorm",
>   "shard": 14,
>   "primary": false
> }
> '
{
  "index" : "denorm",
  "shard" : 14,
  "primary" : false,
  "current_state" : "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info" : {
    "reason" : "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
    "at" : "2020-11-19T13:09:42.072Z",
    "failed_allocation_attempts" : 5,
    "details" : "failed shard on node [ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg]: failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on replica [denorm][14], node[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg], [R], recovery_source[peer recovery], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=WpZNgGsuSoeyHE-Hg_HBSw], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-11-19T13:08:41.492Z], failed_attempts[4], failed_nodes[[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg, 0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]: failed recovery, failure RecoveryFailedException[[denorm][14]: Recovery failed from {platform3}{9ltF-KXGRk-xMF_Ef1DAng}{hdd3KH53Sg6Us8Ow2rVY-A}{10.62.70.179}{10.62.70.179:9300}{dimr} into {platform2}{0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA}{0jbndos9TQq9s-DoSMNjgA}{10.62.70.178}{10.62.70.178:9300}{dimr}]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform3][10.62.70.179:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/start_recovery]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform2][10.62.70.178:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/file_chunk]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4480371114/4.1gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4479322256/4.1gb], new bytes reserved: [1048858/1mb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=1619769/1.5mb, in_flight_requests=2097692/2mb, accounting=119863546/114.3mb]]; ], allocation_status[no_attempt]], expected_shard_size[1168665714], failure RemoteTransportException[[platform1][10.62.70.177:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4516429702/4.2gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4516131576/4.2gb], new bytes reserved: [298126/291.1kb], usages [request=65648/64.1kb, fielddata=1412022/1.3mb, in_flight_requests=29783730/28.4mb, accounting=121642746/116mb]]; ",
    "last_allocation_status" : "no_attempt"
  },
  "can_allocate" : "no",
  "allocate_explanation" : "cannot allocate because allocation is not permitted to any of the nodes",
  "node_allocation_decisions" : [
    {
      "node_id" : "0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA",
      "node_name" : "platform2",
      "transport_address" : "10.62.70.178:9300",
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "shard has exceeded the maximum number of retries [5] on failed allocation attempts - manually call [/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true] to retry, [unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-11-19T13:09:42.072Z], failed_attempts[5], failed_nodes[[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg, 0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg]: failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on replica [denorm][14], node[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg], [R], recovery_source[peer recovery], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=WpZNgGsuSoeyHE-Hg_HBSw], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-11-19T13:08:41.492Z], failed_attempts[4], failed_nodes[[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg, 0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]: failed recovery, failure RecoveryFailedException[[denorm][14]: Recovery failed from {platform3}{9ltF-KXGRk-xMF_Ef1DAng}{hdd3KH53Sg6Us8Ow2rVY-A}{10.62.70.179}{10.62.70.179:9300}{dimr} into {platform2}{0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA}{0jbndos9TQq9s-DoSMNjgA}{10.62.70.178}{10.62.70.178:9300}{dimr}]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform3][10.62.70.179:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/start_recovery]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform2][10.62.70.178:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/file_chunk]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4480371114/4.1gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4479322256/4.1gb], new bytes reserved: [1048858/1mb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=1619769/1.5mb, in_flight_requests=2097692/2mb, accounting=119863546/114.3mb]]; ], allocation_status[no_attempt]], expected_shard_size[1168665714], failure RemoteTransportException[[platform1][10.62.70.177:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4516429702/4.2gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4516131576/4.2gb], new bytes reserved: [298126/291.1kb], usages [request=65648/64.1kb, fielddata=1412022/1.3mb, in_flight_requests=29783730/28.4mb, accounting=121642746/116mb]]; ], allocation_status[no_attempt]]]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "node_id" : "9ltF-KXGRk-xMF_Ef1DAng",
      "node_name" : "platform3",
      "transport_address" : "10.62.70.179:9300",
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "shard has exceeded the maximum number of retries [5] on failed allocation attempts - manually call [/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true] to retry, [unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-11-19T13:09:42.072Z], failed_attempts[5], failed_nodes[[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg, 0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg]: failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on replica [denorm][14], node[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg], [R], recovery_source[peer recovery], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=WpZNgGsuSoeyHE-Hg_HBSw], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-11-19T13:08:41.492Z], failed_attempts[4], failed_nodes[[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg, 0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]: failed recovery, failure RecoveryFailedException[[denorm][14]: Recovery failed from {platform3}{9ltF-KXGRk-xMF_Ef1DAng}{hdd3KH53Sg6Us8Ow2rVY-A}{10.62.70.179}{10.62.70.179:9300}{dimr} into {platform2}{0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA}{0jbndos9TQq9s-DoSMNjgA}{10.62.70.178}{10.62.70.178:9300}{dimr}]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform3][10.62.70.179:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/start_recovery]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform2][10.62.70.178:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/file_chunk]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4480371114/4.1gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4479322256/4.1gb], new bytes reserved: [1048858/1mb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=1619769/1.5mb, in_flight_requests=2097692/2mb, accounting=119863546/114.3mb]]; ], allocation_status[no_attempt]], expected_shard_size[1168665714], failure RemoteTransportException[[platform1][10.62.70.177:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4516429702/4.2gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4516131576/4.2gb], new bytes reserved: [298126/291.1kb], usages [request=65648/64.1kb, fielddata=1412022/1.3mb, in_flight_requests=29783730/28.4mb, accounting=121642746/116mb]]; ], allocation_status[no_attempt]]]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "same_shard",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "the shard cannot be allocated to the same node on which a copy of the shard already exists [[denorm][14], node[9ltF-KXGRk-xMF_Ef1DAng], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=SNyCoFUzSwaiIE4187Tfig]]"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "node_id" : "ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg",
      "node_name" : "platform1",
      "transport_address" : "10.62.70.177:9300",
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "shard has exceeded the maximum number of retries [5] on failed allocation attempts - manually call [/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true] to retry, [unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-11-19T13:09:42.072Z], failed_attempts[5], failed_nodes[[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg, 0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg]: failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on replica [denorm][14], node[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg], [R], recovery_source[peer recovery], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=WpZNgGsuSoeyHE-Hg_HBSw], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-11-19T13:08:41.492Z], failed_attempts[4], failed_nodes[[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg, 0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]: failed recovery, failure RecoveryFailedException[[denorm][14]: Recovery failed from {platform3}{9ltF-KXGRk-xMF_Ef1DAng}{hdd3KH53Sg6Us8Ow2rVY-A}{10.62.70.179}{10.62.70.179:9300}{dimr} into {platform2}{0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA}{0jbndos9TQq9s-DoSMNjgA}{10.62.70.178}{10.62.70.178:9300}{dimr}]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform3][10.62.70.179:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/start_recovery]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform2][10.62.70.178:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/file_chunk]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4480371114/4.1gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4479322256/4.1gb], new bytes reserved: [1048858/1mb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=1619769/1.5mb, in_flight_requests=2097692/2mb, accounting=119863546/114.3mb]]; ], allocation_status[no_attempt]], expected_shard_size[1168665714], failure RemoteTransportException[[platform1][10.62.70.177:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4516429702/4.2gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4516131576/4.2gb], new bytes reserved: [298126/291.1kb], usages [request=65648/64.1kb, fielddata=1412022/1.3mb, in_flight_requests=29783730/28.4mb, accounting=121642746/116mb]]; ], allocation_status[no_attempt]]]"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As mentioned [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/data-too-large-data-for-transport-request-would-be-10554893106-9-8gb-which-is-larger-than-the-limit-of-10092838912-9-3gb-real-usage-10523239224-9-8gb-new-bytes-reserved-31653882-30-1mb/192215/11?u=deb) in node stats I am observing that out of 4.3 GB heap only about ~85 MB is used for keeping in-memory data structures.

As discussed [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/circuitbreakingexception-parent-data-too-large-in-es-7-x/192801) on setting `indices.breaker.total.use_real_memory: false` I am not seeing the `Data too large exception`.

Can some one let me know how can I confirm if I am observing the same issue as discussed [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/44484)?

I did not see this issue with elasticsearch 5.6.16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by @Val in the comment, Due to your [circuit breaker configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/circuit-breaker.html#parent-circuit-breaker) in ES 7.X version, ES couldn't allocate the shard on other data nodes, and now left with node which also holds primary shard.

```
{
      "node_id" : "9ltF-KXGRk-xMF_Ef1DAng",
      "node_name" : "platform3",
      "transport_address" : "10.62.70.179:9300",
      "node_decision" : "no",
      "deciders" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "shard has exceeded the maximum number of retries [5] on failed allocation attempts - manually call [/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true] to retry, [unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-11-19T13:09:42.072Z], failed_attempts[5], failed_nodes[[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg, 0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg]: failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on replica [denorm][14], node[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg], [R], recovery_source[peer recovery], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=WpZNgGsuSoeyHE-Hg_HBSw], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2020-11-19T13:08:41.492Z], failed_attempts[4], failed_nodes[[ocKks7zJT7OODhse-yveyg, 0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]], delayed=false, details[failed shard on node [0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA]: failed recovery, failure RecoveryFailedException[[denorm][14]: Recovery failed from {platform3}{9ltF-KXGRk-xMF_Ef1DAng}{hdd3KH53Sg6Us8Ow2rVY-A}{10.62.70.179}{10.62.70.179:9300}{dimr} into {platform2}{0_00hk5IRcmgrHGYjpV1jA}{0jbndos9TQq9s-DoSMNjgA}{10.62.70.178}{10.62.70.178:9300}{dimr}]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform3][10.62.70.179:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/start_recovery]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[platform2][10.62.70.178:9300][internal:index/shard/recovery/file_chunk]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4480371114/4.1gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4479322256/4.1gb], new bytes reserved: [1048858/1mb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=1619769/1.5mb, in_flight_requests=2097692/2mb, accounting=119863546/114.3mb]]; ], allocation_status[no_attempt]], expected_shard_size[1168665714], failure RemoteTransportException[[platform1][10.62.70.177:9300][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4516429702/4.2gb], which is larger than the limit of [4476560998/4.1gb], real usage: [4516131576/4.2gb], new bytes reserved: [298126/291.1kb], usages [request=65648/64.1kb, fielddata=1412022/1.3mb, in_flight_requests=29783730/28.4mb, accounting=121642746/116mb]]; ], allocation_status[no_attempt]]]"
        },
        {
          "decider" : "same_shard",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "the shard cannot be allocated to the same node on which a copy of the shard already exists [[denorm][14], node[9ltF-KXGRk-xMF_Ef1DAng], [P], s[STARTED], a[id=SNyCoFUzSwaiIE4187Tfig]]"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Note the Error message **CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4480371114/4.1gb]. **

As, Elasticsearch never assigns the primary and its replica shard on the same node due to high availability reasons, hence try to fix the circuit breaker exceptions by tunning its setting to fix the issue.

default allocation retry is just 5 times, and after fixing the issue you can again retry the allocation, by using the below command.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed
```

After running the above command, if you still have a few failures, you might have to reroute the shards manually for which you can [reroute API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html)

**For more background and detailed reading follow [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23199#issuecomment-280272888) and [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23199) link.**

Comment: Is not it like that it failed to allocate shards on platform1 and platform2 due to `Data too large` error and then in platform3 it did not try to put the shard as primary shard is already in platform3 ?

Comment: The fact that the shard cannot be allocated on the same node is a side effect, the root cause is related to `CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [4480371114/4.1gb]`. After failing on the two other nodes because of `CircuitBreakingException` ES tried to allocate the shard to the remaining node which already contained the same shard

Comment: Just to add we are not seeing this issue with elastic search 5.6.16, same number of shards and same number of nodes and same config.

Comment: @tuk Yes, that's a configuration problem around the tuning of circuit breakers

Comment: @Val, thanks for pointing to the actual cause of the circuit breaker, after you mentioned I copied the error, copied separately, and found the log lines of the circuit breaker which I missed when I checked it in the question, which lead me to think that OP might have reduced the no of data nodes or problematic index has large number of replicas, which is causing ES to allocate them on same node

Comment: @Val, updated the answer, thanks once again for correcting :)

Comment: Now, onto finding the right settings for the circuit breakers ;-)